# Cycles - Baking to Image Completely Different to Material

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm completely stuck.  I've spent so many hours trying to find out what I'm doing wrong, but it's the same outcome each time.

I have created some rocks / mountains in Blender that I plan to use in Unity, however the texture looks completely messed up.

I smart uv unwrapped, and created a material using nodes.  I then baked to an image, saved to disk, and imported into Unity.  The model is exported via FBX.

The first image is the material, and that is how I want it to appear.  The second image is texture render (low samples) in the viewport (I added a brightness node, as I don't know how to light something in Cycles (adding a light source didn't do anything)).

As you can see there are issues at the seams, and the colour ramp is messed up.

[image: Blender Material]
[image: Blender Texture]

Edit:  Changed the Bake Type to just "Diffuse", and that solves it.  (Thanks to pycoder for focusing my attention there).

Comment: do you have enough light in your environment ?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your baking settings? It should be set to "Diffuse Color" since you are planning to do the lighting in Unity.

Comment: @lemon I just figured out how to add lighting in Cycles.  Didn't know it had to be baked into the image.  Ideally I don't want lighting baked, as I want Unity to handle how things look.

Comment: @pycoder Sorry, I did try to add them to the post, but am limited to 2 right now, so I uploaded another here...  http://imgur.com/a/hRa5B

Comment: @Jacket Sorry, but I can't get to it. Can you tell me what the settings are?

Comment: @pycoder Bake Type = Combined, Direct & Indirect buttons are default (they look enabled), Diffuse = Ticked, Glossy, Subsurface, AO, Transmission and Emit = All unticked.  Margin = 16px, Clear = Ticked, Selected to Active = Unticked.

Comment: @pycoder I changed the bake type to just "Diffuse" instead of "Combined", and that solved it.  Thanks a ton.  I wouldn't have thought to play with that drop down, as I saw "Diffuse" was ticked, and that was good enough.

Comment: @pycoder Done ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the mode to "Diffuse" in the baking panel then enable only color if you want no lighting:

[image]

Comment: I'm having this issue but like this  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95018/blender-cycles-bake-not-looking-like-object-in-rendered-view. I'm going to give your solution a shot and post back here later. Thanks.