# Blender Cycles Bake Not Looking Like Object in Rendered View

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

I have a couch in Blender that looks like this in rendered view.

[image]

I baked it with a combined texture and this is what it came out to be.

[image]

This is what it looks like added to the mesh.

[image]

Why does the view with the baked image not look exactly like the rendered view?

Does it have something to do with my mesh and faces?

This is my mesh.

[image]

This has never happened to me before as I baked a couple things before this which came out perfectly.

Comment: Same problem here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94947/how-do-i-bake-textures

Answer (score 1):

Did you use Blender to UV the model? It looks like it is UV'ed, but somehow the point order has changed and the UV's and Verts no longer match up.

I sometimes get this problem when I go back and forth between Zbrush and Blender and mess up point orders either during import or export. The UV's may look correct, still, but each polygon in UV space doesn't correspond to the 3D space polygon it was originally assigned to anymore.

Do a simple UV again in Blender and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: that did not solve the problem. I uv unwrapped it with smart uv project and baked it again over and over and it has not changed

Comment: i go back and forth between blender and unity. would that mess it up? But i always unwrap it again

Comment: @Repardeimaj I'm facing this same issue and spent lot of time to fix this but still havent found a way to fix it. Did you find the solution?

Comment: @ChiragMS Did you delete all pre-existing UV maps?

Comment: @JakeD Actually I only have one UVmap. I doubled checked this as many of the other posts mentioned this issue.